# Wpf control for image and video all in one

Tags: wpf

I searched and already read the Wpf documentation but didn't find any usefull answer. So my question is: Is there any control in Wpf (Xaml) that you can display the both, image and video file in it?
I want to make control, where you can choose image or video file from disk with OpenFileManager and then in the Window Form this file is showed (one control for both: image and video)

Answer (score -1):

place two controls at a same position in a grid,based on the file selection enable visibility of suitable element..

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="mediaem"></MediaElement>
            <Image x:Name="img"  Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Hidden"></Image>
        </Grid>
```